# passing coordinates from view to controller through post method

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

I'm trying to pass coordinates values from view to controller `add` taken from geolocation google api but I' having some trouble.well this is the script I'm using in the view named `_add`. the scripts works because javascript console print out coordinates well.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){
            get_location();
        });

        function get_location()
        {
            if(navigator.geolocation)
            {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){

                        var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

                        $.post('http://firstaid:8888/add', { latitude:latitude, longitude:longitude });

                });
            }
        }

    </script>
```

Now I would pass values from this views to controller in this way I can use as variable in php codeigniter controller. To do this I use `$this->input->post`.

```
function index()
{
    $data['title'] = 'Add';

    $latitude = $this->input->post('latitude');

    $this->load->view('templates/_header', $data);
    $this->load->view('_add');

}
```

But when I print out `$latitude`, the variable is blank.where could be is the mistake? maybe because I call post before loading views?

Does it exist another way to pass data to the controller?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this line:

```
$.post('http://firstaid:8888/add', { latitude:latitude, longitude:longitude });
```

to this:

```
$.post('http://firstaid:8888/add', 'latitude='+latitude+'&longitude='+longitude);
```

There's more than one way to skin a cat, of course, as I believe there is a jQuery method that can serialize JSON to proper POST variable string format, but what I have here will certainly work.

Comment: I tried print_r($_POST('latitude')); but I receive this error: Fatal error: Function name must be a string some idea ?

Comment: `$_POST` is an array, not a function. So, to access a member of the array you use square brackets `[]`, like this for example: `print_r($_POST['latitude']);`

Comment: I corrected..what stupid error I commited...anyway I corrected it but I receive always the error the variable it is blank...

Comment: Just to cover all bases, have you tried putting alerts or console.log calls into your javascript code to make sure that the value of position.coords.latitude is not actually blank?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7975/discussion-between-eng-mazzy-and-brian-driscoll)

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing $latitude to the view, so you cannot access it.

If you were loading a new page, $latitude would need to be in the $data array that is passed to the view.

However, you're using Ajax, so you cannot load a new view that way.  You need to do something like:

```
$latitude = $this->input->post('latitude');
echo json_encode( $latitude );
```

Then process the response in your Javascript.

Or just use print_r directly in the controller to confirm the variable is there.

```
print_r($this->input->post('latitude'));
```

Try this in your Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "/add",
     data: "latitude=" + latitude,
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(msg){
         alert('Completed');
     } //End success condition
 }); //End ajax
```

When making the Ajax request in Chrome or Firebug, make sure the "Network" panel is open so you can confirm that it is finding your controller.

Comment: First try this: print_r($this->input->post('latitude'));

Comment: I updated my post.  Try out that Ajax function and make sure the request is going through by inspecting it with the Network panel.

Comment: I tried but no result obtained... I put .ajax at the place of $.post but I receive Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Answer (score 0):

controller file :

```
$this->load->library('googlemaps');

$config['center'] = '37.4419, -122.1419';
$config['zoom'] = 'auto';
$this->googlemaps->initialize($config);

$marker = array();
$marker['position'] = '37.429, -122.1419';
$marker['draggable'] = true;
$marker['ondragend'] = 'updateDatabase(event.latLng.lat(), event.latLng.lng());';
$this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);
$data['map'] = $this->googlemaps->create_map();

$this->load->view('view_file', $data);
```

view file :

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function updateDatabase(newLat, newLng)
        {
            // make an ajax request to a PHP file
            // on our site that will update the database
            // pass in our lat/lng as parameters
            $.post(
                "/my_controller/update_coords", 
                { 'newLat': newLat, 'newLng': newLng, 'var1': 'value1' }
            )
            .done(function(data) {
                alert("Database updated");
            });
        }
    </script>
    <?php echo $map['js']; ?>
</head>
<body><?php echo $map['html']; ?></body>
</html>
```

referenced by : http://biostall.com/demos/google-maps-v3-api-codeigniter-library/updatedatabase